# Predefine selection of Holoviews RangeToolLink

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

Is there a way to adjust the selection range in the RangeToolLink?

By default, the entire area of the plot is selected, which can then be adjusted and/or moved accordingly.

Standard:
[image]

Wish (for example):
[image]

(From https://www.holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/timeseries_range_tool.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Holoviews it is possible to set the underling properties of the figure using a [hook](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html).

In the example below there are two different hooks used for the upper and lower figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.plotting.links import RangeToolLink

hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL['close'], columns=['close'], index=pd.to_datetime(AAPL['date']))
aapl_df.index.name = 'Date'

aapl_curve = hv.Curve(aapl_df, 'Date', ('close', 'Price ($)'))

def hook(plot, element):
    plot.handles['x_range'].start = pd.to_datetime('2006')
    plot.handles['x_range'].end = pd.to_datetime('2008')
tgt = aapl_curve.relabel('AAPL close price').opts(width=800, labelled=['y'], toolbar='disable').opts(hooks=[hook])

def hook(plot, element):
    plot.handles['x_range'].start = pd.to_datetime('2000')
    plot.handles['x_range'].end = pd.to_datetime('2014')
src = aapl_curve.opts(width=800, height=100, yaxis=None, default_tools=[]).opts(hooks=[hook])

RangeToolLink(src, tgt)

layout = (tgt + src).cols(1)
layout.opts(opts.Layout(shared_axes=False, merge_tools=False))
```

[image: result after modification of the range tool]

The result is very similar to the [range_tool example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/range_tool.html) of the bokeh library.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to set the range hook on the rangetool element, just the data curve plot

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.plotting.links import RangeToolLink

hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL['close'], columns=['close'], index=pd.to_datetime(AAPL['date']))
aapl_df.index.name = 'Date'

aapl_curve = hv.Curve(aapl_df, 'Date', ('close', 'Price ($)'))

def hook(plot, element):
    plot.handles['x_range'].start = pd.to_datetime('2006')
    plot.handles['x_range'].end = pd.to_datetime('2008')
tgt = aapl_curve.relabel('AAPL close price').opts(width=800, labelled=['y'], toolbar='disable').opts(hooks=[hook])

src = aapl_curve.opts(width=800, height=100, yaxis=None, default_tools=[])

RangeToolLink(src, tgt)

layout = (tgt + src).cols(1)
layout.opts(opts.Layout(shared_axes=False, merge_tools=False))
```

[image]